# Count characters from textarea when document ready and keyup

Tags: jquery

I want to count how many characters inside textarea (if any) when the page is loaded on the screen for the first time. then I also want to show it when user add more characters or delete some of it.

My HTML Code :

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="textBox" class="form-control" rows="10">Hello world</textarea>
    <div id="charNum"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and I have this jQuery script :

```
function countChar() {
    var len = val.value.length;
    $('#charNum').text(len+' characters');
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    countChar();
    $('#textBox').change(countChar);
    $('#textBox').keyup(countChar);
});
```

but it's not displaying result as I wanted, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tvo4asdy/1/

Comment: (1) `val` is not defined in `var len = val.value.length;` so you can't get `value.length` of undefined and (2) you have a syntax error in `$('#charNum').text(len+' characters);` as you are missing the closing qoute `'` after `characters`

Comment: @ArunPJohny : it works, bro... why don't you post it as an answer, instead of comment?

Comment: This is a typo error question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your script

1. A syntax issue with a unclosed `'`
2. The way how you are reading the textarea value is wrong, use a [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to get the textarea and then use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to read the value

```js
function countChar() {
  var len = $('#textBox').val().length;
  $('#charNum').text(len + ' characters');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  countChar();
  $('#textBox').change(countChar);
  $('#textBox').keyup(countChar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="textBox" class="form-control" rows="10">Hello world</textarea>
    <div id="charNum"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version that allows using `this` inside countChar()

```
function countChar() {
    // since only used as event handler callback reference have access to `this`
    var len = this.value.length;
    $('#charNum').text(len + ' characters');
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    // trigger event on page load to set first count
    $('#textBox').change(countChar).change();
    $('#textBox').keyup(countChar);

    /* or combine both events and trigger one of them on page load */
     $('#textBox').on('change keyup', countChar).change();

});
```

Since the function is only ever used as a reference for event handler it will automatically expose `this` as the element instance

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8eq0mnbL/)**</kbd>